Diferencia entre usar un salto o llamada directa a una función de una librería dinámica, con usar el calculo de la dirección plt
Estaba programando con una bibliotéca dinámica en NASM y me encontré con algo relamnete único.
Al usar un salto o llamada directa como call print a mi bibliotéca dinámica, mi código funciona perfectamente.
mov rdi, msg.pointer
mov rsi, msg.length
call print

Lo cual se me hace raro debido a que se supone que debo calcular la dirección plt para poder usar mi "función" print.
El cálculo a la dirección plt lo realizaba de la siguiente manera:
lea rax, [rel print wrt ..plt]
mov rdi, msg.pointer
mov rsi, msg.length
call rax

En ambos casos el código funciona sin ningún problema.
Solo que no entiendo la razón del por que funciona en el primer caso, si nunca calculo la dirección plt para invocar mi función.

En qué sistema operativo? Cada uno tiene su propia ABI

Linux distro Lubuntu (basada en Ubuntu)

En ambos casos estás accediendo a la misma dirección en la PLT. Aún cuando con call print el linker genera una llamada a print@plt. En el primer caso, se genera código para un salto absoluto a print@plt y en el segundo un salto relativo a RIP... pero la dirección final es la misma, la entrada en la PLT. Usa objdump para ver el código generado en ambos casos

@RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor Desde ahora soy seguidor oficial de tu revista.

@RevistaOnlineOccam'sRazor Pública la respuesta para darte indicar quea tuya es la correcta.

Se agradece!!! ;)

En la respuesta lo corrijo. No es un salto relativo sino que es la dirección de la PLT la que se calcula de forma relativa

En ambos casos, el código efectivamente calcula la misma dirección que no es otra que la entrada asociada a la función print en la PLT (Procedure Linkage Table), la cual es generada por el linker para binarios dinámicos.
Para el primer caso el código generado es:
$ objdump -d main

main:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000401000 <print@plt-0x10>:
  401000:   ff 35 ea 2f 00 00       push   0x2fea(%rip)        # 403ff0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  401006:   ff 25 ec 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fec(%rip)        # 403ff8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  40100c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000401010 <print@plt>:
  401010:   ff 25 ea 2f 00 00       jmp    *0x2fea(%rip)        # 404000 <print>
  401016:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
  40101b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmp    401000 <msg.length+0x400ff3>

(...)

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401030 <_start>:
  401030:   48 bf 00 20 40 00 00    movabs $0x402000,%rdi
  401037:   00 00 00
  40103a:   be 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%esi
  40103f:   e8 cc ff ff ff          call   401010 <print@plt>
  401044:   e9 d7 ff ff ff          jmp    401020 <exit@plt>

En ese caso, el linker calcula la dirección absoluta a la entrada PLT para print. En el segundo caso, la sección PLT es idéntica (no incluida en la salida de objdump debajo) si bien el código generado utiliza direccionamiento indirecto a RIP para obtener la misma dirección:
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401030 <_start>:
  401030:   48 bf 00 20 40 00 00    movabs $0x402000,%rdi
  401037:   00 00 00
  40103a:   be 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%esi
  40103f:   48 8d 05 ca ff ff ff    lea    -0x36(%rip),%rax        # 401010 <print@plt>
  401046:   ff d0                   call   *%rax
  401048:   e9 d3 ff ff ff          jmp    401020 <exit@plt>

Sin embargo en ambos casos la función a la que se llama está en la misma dirección 0x401010 en este ejemplo. Nótese sin embargo, que el segundo código el cálculo de la dirección final es independiente de la posición en memoria del binario (PIE) mientras que el primero requiere posiciones predeterminadas (no-PIE).
